# Searching over a templated tree

Tags: c#, tree

So I have 2 interfaces:

A node that can have children

```
public interface INode
{
    IEnumeration<INode> Children { get; }
    void AddChild(INode node);
}
```

And a derived "Data Node" that can have data associated with it

```
public interface IDataNode<DataType> : INode
{
    DataType Data;
    IDataNode<DataType> FindNode(DataType dt);
}
```

Keep in mind that each node in the tree could have a different data type associated with it as its Data (because the INode.AddChild function just takes the base INode)

Here is the implementation of the IDataNode interface:

```
internal class DataNode<DataType> : IDataNode<DataType>
{
    List<INode> m_Children;

    DataNode(DataType dt)
    {
        Data = dt;
    }

    public IEnumerable<INode> Children
    {
        get { return m_Children; }
    }

    public void AddChild(INode node)
    {
        if (null == m_Children)
            m_Children = new List<INode>();

        m_Children.Add(node);
    }   

    public DataType Data { get; private set; }
```

Question is how do I implement the FindNode function without knowing what kinds of DataType I will encounter in the tree?

```
    public IDataNode<DataType> FindNode(DataType dt)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();    
    }
}
```

As you can imagine something like this will not work out

```
    public IDataNode<DataType> FindNode(DataType dt)
    {
        IDataNode<DataType> result = null;

        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            if (child is IDataNode<DataType>)
            {
                var datachild = child as IDataNode<DataType>;

                if (datachild.Data.Equals(dt))
                {
                    result = child as IDataNode<DataType>;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                 // What??
            }

            // Need to recursively call FindNode on the child
            // but can't because it could have a different
            // DataType associated with it. Can't call FindNode 
            // on child because it is of type INode and not IDataNode
            result = child.FindNode(dt); // can't do this!

            if (null != result)
                break;
       }

       return result; 
    }
```

Is my only option to do this when I know what kinds of DataType a particular tree I use will have? Maybe I am going about this in the wrong way, so any tips are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is `FindNode` supposed to do? And why is it defined only in `IDataNode` and not in `INode`?

Comment: I just updated my question to add a comment in the code explaining why I cannot call FindNode on child. @Jon, FindNode is only relevant when you have data in the node (which INode doesn't have, only IDataNode has it). FindNode will find the first descendant node that has data that is equal to the passed in data.

Comment: I asked these questions because answering them will help you towards a solution. First, does it not sound unnatural to you that you would need to find an `IDataNode<DataType>` *before* being able to call `FindNode` at all? How would you find it? How would you find your first `IDataNode<int>`, considering that you cannot call `FindNode(int)` before doing that? Clearly, the code needs to be reworked. I 'll provide an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to put the `FindNode` method in `INode`. Otherwise, you cannot find a node of some type `DataType`... before having found a node of type `DataType`. Even if you have a reference to an object that you *know* is a `DataNode<X>`, this won't help you if someone tells you to find a `DataNode<Y>`.

There are now two roads you may take: if you want `DataNode` to be templated, then you need to know all possible types of data in the tree at compile time. If you know that, you can use a generic `DataNode`. If there's a chance that you may want to find a node with data of some type that will only become known to you at runtime (e.g. from the return value of some method that you do not control) then you cannot use generics.

I will illustrate the generic solution below.

```
public interface INode
{
    IEnumerable<INode> Children { get; }
    IDataNode<DataType> FindNode<DataType>(DataType value);
    void AddChild(INode node);
}

public interface IDataNode<DataType> : INode
{
    DataType Data { get; }
}
```

`INode.FindNode` could be implemented like this:

```
public IDataNode<DataType> FindNode<DataType> (DataType value) {
    // If we are searching for ourselves, return this
    var self = this as IDataNode<DataType>;
    if (self != null && self.Data.Equals(value)) {
        return self;
    }

    // Otherwise:
    // 1. For each of our children, call FindNode on it. This will
    //    find the target node if it is our child, since each child
    //    will check if it is the node we look for, like we did above.
    // 2. If our child is not the one we are looking for, FindNode will
    //    continue looking into its own children (depth-first search).
    // 3. Return the first descendant that comes back and is not null.
    //    If no node is found, FirstOrDefault means we will return null.
    return this.children.Select(c => c.FindNode(value))
                        .FirstOrDefault(found => found != null);
}
```

I have to say that the above recursive implementation with LINQ tries perhaps to be too clever and is maybe not very easy to understand. It could always be written with `foreach`, to make it more clear.

Comment: That is indeed very clever. Thanks for the great answer and explanation!

Comment: I ended up implementing it slightly differently, mainly because I didn't want the 'INode' interface to know about a type derived from it i.e. 'IDataNode'). To do that I had to add another templated method - 'bool Equals<SomeDataType>(SomeDataType sdt)'. Also 'FindNode' was changed - 'INode FindNode<SomeDataType>(SomeDataType sdt)'.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Generic Function:

```
public IDataNode<DataType> FindNode<DataType>(DataType dt)
{
    IDataNode<DataType> result = null;

    foreach (var child in Children)
    {
        if (child is IDataNode<DataType>)
        {
            var datachild = child as IDataNode<DataType>;

            if (datachild.Data.Equals(dt))
            {
                result = child as IDataNode<DataType>;
                break;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
             // it's not a DataType You're looking for, so ignore it!
        }
   }

   return result; 
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
var resultsStr = tree.FindNode<string>("Hello");
var resultsInt = tree.FindNode<int>(5);
var resultsCust = tree.FindNode<MyCustomClass>(new MyCustomClass("something"));
```

Comment: I updated my earlier question to make it more clear. In your solution above, I could still have children of nodes that I skip over that are the data type I am looking for. Where do you recurse?